# Unable to read from terraform.tfstate while using modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform v0.12.6. I am using modules to create a VPC,Subnets and EC2 instances.

```
root.tf 
   vpc.tf
   pub_subnet.tf
   web_server.tf
```

vpc.tf and pub_subnet.tf are working fine and displaying the required output. However, I am unable to use the subnet_id from the module pub_subnet.tf as input to my web_server.tf.

The reason being that it is a list and I am getting Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.

Looks like I have to read the terraform.tfstate file.

Here is my present code -

root.tf

```
    provider "aws" {
      region = "us-east-1"
    }
    data "terraform_remote_state" "public_subnet" {
    backend = "local"
    config = {
      path = "terraform.tfstate"
    }
    }
    module "my_vpc" {
      source = "../modules/vpc_flowlogs"
      vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
     # vpc_id  = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
       }

    module "vpc_igw" {
      source = "../modules/vpc_igw"  
      vpc_id  = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"

    }
    module "public_subnets" {
      source="../modules/pub_subnets"
      vpc_id  = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
    }

     module "web_servers" {
    source = "../modules/webservers"
    vpc_id  = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
    subnet_id = 
    "${data.terraform_remote_state.public_subnet.outputs.subnet_id[0]}"
    }
```

web_servers.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "web-srvs" {
count="${var.instance_count == "0" ? "1" : var.instance_count}"
ami = "ami-035b3c7efe6d061d5"
instance_type = "t2.nano"
key_name="xxx-dev"
subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.pub_sg.id}"]
associate_public_ip_address=true
}
```

I am trying to use of the two subnet_ids created.
I have tried different ways but now running out of ideas. 
Just as an FYI, my tfstate file is located in the same directory as root.tf

Appreciate any help. OR is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting a remote state for no reason. Remote state is for referencing output from other configs. You have modules so you should just change it to reference the module resource, but you are going to have to output the values in the module so you can reference it elsewhere.

```
subnet_id = 
    "${data.terraform_remote_state.public_subnet.outputs.subnet_id[0]}"
    } 

Should be

subnet_id = 
    "${module.public_subnets.subnet.id}"
    }
```

In your subnet module, create an output resource.

```
output "subnet" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.some_subnet.id}"
}
```

Comment: I made the following changes   subnet_id = "${module.public_subnets.subnet.id}" and created an output  -- output  "subnet_id" { value = "${aws_subnet.public_subnet.id}"
}  I am getting the following error -- Error: Missing resource instance key

  on ../modules/pub_subnets/output.tf line 2, in output "subnet_id":
   2:   value = "${aws_subnet.public_subnet.id}"

Because aws_subnet.public_subnet has "count" set, its attributes must be
accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    aws_subnet.public_subnet[count.index]

Comment: Can you post your subnet module code? Based on the error message you are creating more than one subnet, this creates an additional challenge. EC2 instances can only be launched in one subnet. So there needs to be some additional logic to determine what subnet you want the instance launched. The output value can be changed to "${aws_subnet.some_subnet.*.id} to output all subnets created with the count method. But you will need to pick one to launch the instance in, or if you want to create an instance in each subnet.

Comment: `resource aws_subnet "public_subnet"{
count=2
vpc_id="${var.vpc_id}"
cidr_block="${var.sub_cdr[count.index]}"
availability_zone="${data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index]}"
tags= {Name = "pub-sub-${count.index + 1}"}
}`

Comment: `output  "subnet_id" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id}"
}`

Comment: Did this help? the output might need to be ids instead of id. Since there are more than one.

Comment: It did not. **Error: Unsupported attribute**